# How to match column value to column name?

Tags: php, mysqli

I am trying get value from `shipping_charge` table. I have two tables one is `pincode` table and second is `shipping_charge` table. When user enter pincode, I fetch data from `pincode` table to check zone. So, I cant understand how to match fetched 'zone' value to get shipping charge from `shipping_charge` table. Shipping charges include in `city` and `metro` column. I provide table for example.

Here is my `pincode` table:

```
______________________
|id|pincode|cod|zone |
----------------------
|1 |100001 | Y |city |

|2 |100002 | N |City |

|3 |100003 | N |metro|

|4 |100004 | Y |City |

|5 |100005 | Y |City |

----------------------
```

Here is my `shipping_charge` table:

```
________________________
|id|pro_code|city|metro|
------------------------
|1 |pro0001 |100 |150  |

|2 |pro0002 |50  |100  |

|3 |pro0003 |150 |200  |

|4 |pro0004 |100 |120  |

------------------------
```

I tryed only this code to get zone

```
$result= $this->connect()->query("SELECT * FROM wm_pincode WHERE 
pincode='$pincode'");
    if($result->num_rows>0){
        $row=$result->fetch_assoc();
        $zone =$row['zone'];
    }
```

If user enter `pro_code= pro0002` and `pincode=100003` then get `zone=metro` and `shipping charge=100`.

So how is it.

Comment: note: if `$pincode` is got via user input, you're open to SQL injection and should address immediately

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to use two queries:

```
$result= $this->connect()->query("SELECT * FROM wm_pincode WHERE 
pincode='$pincode'");
    if($result->num_rows>0){
        $row=$result->fetch_assoc();
        $zone =strtolower($row['zone']);
        $result= $this->connect()->query("SELECT $zone as shipping_charge_value FROM shipping_charge WHERE 
pro_code='$procode'");
        if($result->num_rows>0){
            $row=$result->fetch_assoc();
            $shipping_charge =$row['shipping_charge_value'];
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use `union all`

```
select charge,zone from (
select metro as charge,'metro' as namezone,pro_code from shipping_charge
  union all
select city as charge,'city' as namezone,pro_code from shipping_charge)
as DD,pincode sc where DD.pro_code='pro0002' and DD.namezone=sc.zone and sc.pincode=100003
```